# Eclipse E4: how to access the MApplication instance (at start)

Tags: java, eclipse, model, eclipse-rcp, e4

Trying to access the MApplication instance at startup: that is, before the user accesses the UI to generate events, via buttons, views etc.

It appears that at startup, there are 2 access points:

1. The app osgi bundle activator: via the .start() method.
2. The E4LifeCycle instance: the .postContextCreate(workbenchContext, applicationContext) method.

In checking the initial workbenchContext in my E4LifeCycle instance, it does not return an MApplication instance (or any instanceof MApplicationElement). The IApplicationContext instance (eclipse standard, not e4 apparently) doesn't seem to have any way to get to the e4 elements. The workbenchContext returns an instance of EModelService when queried but (for some reason I can't figure out), one can't access the root model element from that service: one already has to have access to an applicationElement (usually an MUIElement instance) to find other elements.

So, perhaps I'm missing something, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get to the MApplication instance unless it is through the initial mPart view objects (via injection) that one's app provides. Is there no other way to access the app model before the ui/views are created?

Is there some sort of EventBroker I need to register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MApplication` has not yet been created when the life cycle `@PostContextCreate` is called.

It is available when the `@ProcessAdditions` life cycle method is called:

```
@ProcessAdditions
void processAdditions(MApplication app)
```

However you should note that this is still quite early in the application startup so other things may not be available. You may want to subscribe to the `UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE` event in the event broker. This will be called when the application startup is complete.

Comment: Well i'll be darned. Thanks, Greg.